# How to make 2checkout's demo machine return to my local machine?

Tags: 2checkout

I set the return URL to:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_url" value="http://localhost/callback" />
```

Problem is, it still redirects me to the server. I was hoping demo mode would make localhost an acceptable return URL. I can't change the return URL for the current live system, because it is currently in USE by the live system. So how do I test my new implementation using the same account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2Checkout only allows the return URL to be another location on your domain. So I made a php file that basically grabs all the input 2checkout posts to it, and then pass it on to localhost. This is fine for testing purposes for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set your approved URL in your 2Checkout account under the Site Management page in your admin area.

If you are testing, I would also recommend that you use a [free sandbox account](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/sandbox) instead of demo mode on your production account because sandbox accounts will let you test the full lifecycle of a sale including the passback, notifications, recurring installments and fraud review.